# Why is my coordinate notation different?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, wgs84

I was working on a project in WGS84, and I was continually adding layers to it. As I was rendering in print composer and enabled grid-coordinates, I noticed that my coordinates were different. It's supposed to be somewhere 14 north and 121 east (Manila, Philippines).

Can anyone explain how and why this happened, as well as a fix?

[image: QGIS coordinates in canvas view below appear to be depicting something else]

[image: Print Composer: Left map is picking up the units of the odd coordinate numbers]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not really sure but maybe check if you meant EPSG 4326 instead of 3857.

Comment: You're right. 3857 is Pseudo Mercator.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the CRS setting in preferences, and it was wrong.

Comment: QGIS automatically shifted to Pseudo Mercator when I clicked the GE plugin, and there's no way out except to georeference your own satellite layers.